# How can I make one function to load various ifram?

Tags: jquery, iframe, load

Hie I have various pages to load to the same iframe, so I have these functions

```
$("#a1").click(function () { 
      $("#frame").attr("src", "page1.html");
});
$("#a2").click(function () { 
      $("#frame").attr("src", "page2.html");
});
$("#a3").click(function () { 
      $("#frame").attr("src", "page3.html");
});
```

How can I make juste one function in order that the function load `"page"+numid+".html"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [**Multiple Selector ("selector1, selector2, selectorN")**](https://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

```
$("#a1, #a2, #a3").click(function () { 
     var num = this.id.match(/\d+/)[0]; //Extract number from ID
     $("#frame").attr("src", "page"+num +".html");
});
```

Or

You can use [**Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/), Although I don't recommend

```
$("[id^=a]").click(function () { 
     var num = this.id.match(/\d+/)[0]; //Extract number from ID
     $("#frame").attr("src", "page"+num +".html");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use attribute selector **[`[attribute='value']`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)** for selecting elements with id , to select id starting with `a` use [**`[id^='a']`**](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) .
 Use **[`slice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice)** to get the number

```
$("[id^=a]").click(function () { 
      $("#frame").attr("src", "page" + this.id.slice(1) + ".html/");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Attribute Starts With Selector [name^="value"]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$("[id^=a]").click(function () { 
      $("#frame").attr("src", "page"+this.id.replace('a')+".html");
});
```

---

or

`.match(/\d+$/)[0]` to get number from the id

```
$("[id^=a]").click(function () { 
      $("#frame").attr("src", "page"+this.id.match(/\d+$/)[0]+".html");
});
```

---

`$("[id^=a]")` --> all elements starting with id `a`